# ! Misplaced \omit. in doxygen autogenerated output

Tags: compiling, longtabu

I am feeding following input into doxygen -> generate latex (this is simple CANVAS board):

```
 @section book_canvas CANVAS analysis
 <center><table>
 <tr><th colspan="2">Key Partners<th colspan="2">Key Activities<th colspan="2">Value Propositions<th colspan="2">Customer Relationship<th colspan="2">Customer Segment
 <tr><td colspan="2" rowspan="3">Test<td colspan="2">Test<td colspan="2" rowspan="3">Test<td colspan="2">Test<td colspan="2" rowspan="3">Test
 <tr><th colspan="2">Key Resources<th colspan="2">Channels
 <tr><td colspan="2">Test<td colspan="2">Test
 <tr><th colspan="5">Cost Structure<th colspan="5">Revenue Streams
 <tr><td colspan="5">Test<td colspan="5">Test
 </table></center>
```

which gets generated into:

```
\begin{center}\tabulinesep=1mm
\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt [c]{*{10}{|X[-1]}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Key Partners}}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Key Activities}}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Value Propositions}}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Customer Relationship}}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Customer Segment }}\\\cline{1-10}
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\rowcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Key Partners}}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Key Activities}}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Value Propositions}}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Customer Relationship}}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Customer Segment }}\\\cline{1-10}
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\multirow{3}{\linewidth}{Test}}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{Test}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\multirow{3}{\linewidth}{Test}}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{Test}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\multirow{3}{\linewidth}{Test }}\\\cline{3-4}\cline{7-8}
\rowcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Key Resources}}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Channels }}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}\\\cline{3-4}\cline{7-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{Test}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{Test }&\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}\\\cline{1-10}
\rowcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\multicolumn{5}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*2)*5/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Cost Structure}}&\multicolumn{5}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*2)*5/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Revenue Streams }}\\\cline{1-10}
\multicolumn{5}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*2)*5/10}|}{Test}&\multicolumn{5}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*2)*5/10}|}{Test }\\\cline{1-10}
\end{longtabu}
\end{center}
```

When I run latex make.bat over it, I've got:

```
(./book.tex [5] (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/uwasy.fd)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit
                   \@multispan
l.58 \end{longtabu}
```

When using HTML, the output looks just fine.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't provide a usable test document but when I added some guessed definitions it worked if I commented out the `\rowcolor`. `\rowcolor` is supposed to work in that position, and does in `longtable`, but `tabu` seems to have changed the definition somewhere.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu,calc,colortbl,multirow}
\newcommand\tableheadbgcolor{red}
\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{*{10}{|l|}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}%
\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Key Partners}}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Key Activities}}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Value Propositions}}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Customer Relationship}}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Customer Segment }}\\\cline{1-10}
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow}
\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Key Partners}}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Key Activities}}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Value Propositions}}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Customer Relationship}}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Customer Segment }}\\\cline{1-10}
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{
\multirow{3}{\linewidth}{Test}}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{Test}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{
\multirow{3}{\linewidth}{Test}}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{Test}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*5)*2/10}|}{
\multirow{3}{\linewidth}{Test }}\\\cline{3-4}\cline{7-8}
\rowcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}
\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Key Resources}}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Channels }}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}\\\cline{3-4}\cline{7-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{Test}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{Test }&
\multicolumn{2}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*3)*2/10}|}{}\\\cline{1-10}
\rowcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}
\multicolumn{5}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*2)*5/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Cost Structure}}&
\multicolumn{5}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*2)*5/10}|}{\cellcolor{\tableheadbgcolor}\textbf{ Revenue Streams }}\\\cline{1-10}
\multicolumn{5}{|p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*2)*5/10}|}{Test}&
\multicolumn{5}{p{(\linewidth-\tabcolsep*10-\arrayrulewidth*2)*5/10}|}{Test }\\\cline{1-10}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I actually made incorrect assumption about using <th> below first row in the doxygen in the first place. While your solution did compile, it still gave incorrect output... I changed <th> into <td> and used <b> for headers </b> and the problem was solved out